# Hibernate: group by in join

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, orm

I have the following entities in my database:

- Ticket
- Ticket Entry

A Ticket Entry is linked to a Ticket and has a column that references the Ticket ID. I want to retrieve tickets that are linked to only 1 Ticket Entry. I figured out what the SQL script should look like but I don't know how I should convert it to Hibernate code.

```
select * from
tickets ticket
 join
ticket_entries entry on ticket.id=entry.ticket_id
group by ticket.id
having count(*) = 1
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just leaving this link here
https://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/group#GROUP_BY_with_HAVING_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try the following HQL:

```
select t.id
from tickets t join t.ticket_entries entry
group by t.id
having count(*) = 1
```

The major difference from your raw SQL query is that in HQL the join does not require an `ON` clause.  Rather, the definitions of the entities define what the join relation is.

Note that `select *` in combination with `group by` is generally not allowed or at the very least not advisable.  Instead, you should only be selecting the ticket `id` here or maybe some other aggregate.

Answer (score 3):

Very similar in HQL, just change the joins a bit:

```
select ticket.id, count(entry.id) 
from
tickets ticket
 join ticket.ticket_entries entry
group by ticket.id
having count(entry.id) = 1
```

Just remember that you will get a `List<Object[]>` from that query and you need to extract the data apropriately in your logic.

Comment: Since he's expecting the count to be one i suppose it is superfluous, thus he could get the whole entity or just the id to avoid the List<Object>

Comment: Some databases, like oracle as i remember, expect to have the column, aggregate to be part of the select in order for it to be used in the group by / having statements.

Comment: i seem to recall something of the sort now that you mention it, but i just tried with mysql oracle and sqlServer and all seems to be fine without the count in select... maybe its from some version... oh well better be safe